# How to convert C# code to C++

Tags: c#

I have a Data Structure class written in C#. How to convert that to C++ (managed)?

Comment: I think you'll need to provide more information on what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't convert it.  One of the very nice features of .NET is that the types from one managed language can be used in another.  Right-click your C++/CLI project, Properties, Common Properties, Framework and References.  Click Add New Reference.  Use the Projects tab if your C# project is in the same solution (recommended).  Otherwise click the Browse tab and navigate to your C# assembly.

Answer (score 1):

You can see how this is done in the [Classes and Structs (Managed)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6w96b5h7(VS.80).aspx) page on MSDN.  Just put the equivalent types and logic into your C++ `ref class`, and you'll make a managed class in C++.